# How to get all the li checked boxes in a ul from c# code

Tags: c#, html, checkbox

I have an aspx file that looks like this

```
<ul id="test" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">
   <li id=1 runat="server"><input type="checkbox" value=1> One </li>
   <li id=2 runat="server"><input type="checkbox" value=2> Two </li>
   <li id=3 runat="server"><input type="checkbox" value=3> Three </li>
   <li id=4 runat="server"><input type="checkbox" value=4> Four </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get all the li elements that are checked from the c# code?  I know I can do it with jquery in javascript with this:

```
var list = $('#test input:checked');
```

Is there an easy way to do this in c# too?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NSoup library to relatively easy parse a html document

Comment: How you will define which item is checked?

Answer (score 0):

I think if all the < li > elements are runat=server, or created on the server side using test.controls.add(), then you can access them from server side using text.Controls.

Other than that, you can use a XML Parser to parse the innerHTML of the test control.  That will also give you access to attributes and controls of the < li > elements.

Let me know if you need code snippets.

Comment: Just realized the <li> actually created bullets.  Fixed by adding space.

Comment: The <li> elements don't currently have runat="server" but I could probably add it.

Comment: Yes, those are the two I can come up with from the top of my head...The first one, I haven't tested, but in theory should work.  The second one will work, and pretty easy to do using .Net's XML framework, or LINQ.